# What is the easiest way to debug embedded jython in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, embedded, jython, pydev

I know I can debug embedded (launched from a Java program) Jython with a remote Pydev debugger. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really... whenever you're using java and jython, the primary one should be run as usual (as a simple run or debug) and the other one must be remotely debugged.